# Javascript code not being executed in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, execute

I have a problem in regards to using .execute in Nightwatch.

When I run this code in the DOM, it works perfectly. However when I wrap it in an execute command in Nightwatch, it does not even make it to the first click. So probably the execute command is never being executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
LoopThroughQuestions: function() {
        this.waitForElementVisible('.next-button', constants.timeout.medium);                         
         this.api.execute(function() {
            var checkQuestion = function() {
                var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');
                var answers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-row.key');
                answers[0].click();
                nextButton.click();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (document.querySelector('.next-button')) {
                         checkQuestion();
                    } else {
                        console.log("Exit");
                    }
                }, 2000, "Running")
            }
        }, [])   ;

        return this;
    },
```

Comment: According to Game of Thrones, a lot more commands are ignored. (Sorry for this comment, my inner self couldn't help it.)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the variable checkQuestion as a function, but you never call that function.

Try something like this:

```
LoopThroughQuestions: function() {
        this.waitForElementVisible('.next-button', constants.timeout.medium);                         
         this.api.execute(function() {
            var checkQuestion = function() {
                var nextButton = document.querySelector('.next-button');
                var answers = document.querySelectorAll('.flex-row.key');
                answers[0].click();
                nextButton.click();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (document.querySelector('.next-button')) {
                         checkQuestion();
                    } else {
                        console.log("Exit");
                    }
                }, 2000, "Running")
                checkQuestion();
            }
        }, [])   ;

        return this;
    },
```

Recall that you can use a self invoking, anonymous function, too.

```
(function () {
  // body of the function
}());
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however this does not work for me.

Comment: You're going to have to take your LoopThroughQuestions function apart and figure it out. What I can say is that you have defined a function that you never call. You should not expect it to run. You might define it as a anonymous, self invoking function.  I have added an example.

Answer (score 0):

For people who experience the same problem; I fixed it with executeAsync, the script was being executed but the waiting on an element was insufficient

```
 TestLoop: function() {
        this.waitForElementVisible('.next-button', constants.timeout.medium);
        this.api.executeAsync(function() {
            let checkQuestion = function() {
                let nextButton = document.querySelectorAll('.next-button');
                let answers = document.getElementsByClassName('flex-row');
                let blueButton = document.querySelectorAll('.blue-inverse-button').length;
                answers[0].click();
                nextButton[0].click();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (document.querySelectorAll('.next-button')) {
                        console.log('Answering another question!');
                        checkQuestion();
                    }
                    if (blueButton === 1){
                        blueButton[0].click()
                        checkQuestion()
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Exiting?");
                    }
                }, 2000);
            };

            // Initiating the check question function
            return checkQuestion();

        },[], function(){
            console.log('Done?')
        });
    },
```